# Accesing array elements in logstash

Tags: logstash, gsub

I am trying to convert this date structure YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in logstash.
Here is my filter :

```
filter {


    csv {
        separator => " "

        columns => ["date","abc","xyz"]
    }

    mutate {

        split => ["date", "_"]
        gsub => [date[1]","-",":"]
        join => [“date”, “ ”] 
    }

}
```

But I cannot seem to access date[1] though it exists, sniipet from the JSON results:

```
                 "date" => [
  [0] "2014-09-22",
  [1] "02-35-56" ],
```

What is the correct syntax to access date[1] ? If none exists, what would be an alternate filter to transform this date structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [ruby](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby) filter

```
filter{
    ruby {
        code => "
             temp = event['date']
             event['date'] = temp.split('_')[0] + ' '+ temp.split('_')[1].gsub('-',':')
        "
    }
}
```

Use ruby code to transform  the date.